# Mvc Pagination system using months instead of page numbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to make a pagination system for a notifications list which, essentially, should split the list of notifications by month. 
This is my notifications view model:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string Template { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the corresponding view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<IndexViewModel>
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";

    var now = DateTime.Now;
  }

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Resources/styles/Notifications/NotificationsPage.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

  @foreach (IndexViewModel item in Model)
  { 
    <div>
       @Html.Raw(item.Template)
    </div> 
  }
```

I need a very simple solution. Any idea greatly appreciated.

This is the service method that returns my viewmodel

```
public List<IndexViewModel> GetIndexViewModel(int? month, int? year )//(DateTime? entryDate)
    {
        //List<string> templates = GetRenderTemplates(true);

        //Tuple<template, Created, ImportanceId>
        List<Tuple<string, DateTime, int>> templates = GetTemplatesWithDateAndImportance(true);
        templates = templates.OrderBy(f => f.Item3).ThenByDescending(f => f.Item2).Select(f => f).ToList();

        if (month != null && year != null)
            templates = templates.Where(f => f.Item2.Month == month && f.Item2.Year == year).ToList();

        List<IndexViewModel> toRet = new List<IndexViewModel>();

        foreach (Tuple<string, DateTime, int> template in templates)
        {
            toRet.Add(new IndexViewModel() { 
                Template = template.Item1,  
                Created = template.Item2
            });
        }

        return toRet;
    }
```

This is my action:

```
[ActionName("List")]
    public ActionResult UsersList(int? month, int? year)
    {
        List<IndexViewModel> responseModel = Service.GetIndexViewModel(month, year);                            

        return View(responseModel);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? What have you tried? What is your database provider?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, my question is how to make a pagination system which uses month's names instead of page numbers. My database provider is MySQL. I tried to make an action that returns notification templates based on month and year.

Comment: On presentation you can use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(monthNumber);` to represent month name converted from number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
var filteredNotifications = Model.Where(x => x.Created.Month == selectedTime.Month && x.Created.Year == selectedTime.Year);
```

Or (if you're positive they're sorted):

```
var filteredNotifications = Model.SkipWhile(x => x.Created.Month != selectedTime.Month || x.Created.Year != selectedTime.Year).TakeWhile(x => x.Created.Month == selectedTime.Month && x.Created.Year == selectedTime.Year);
```

With `selectedTime` being a `DateTime`, `selectedTime.Month` would be a default month (probably `now.Month`, if no desired value has been suppled) or the selected month (if a desired value has been supplied). The desired value of the month would most probably be a route value. Same goes for `selectedTime.Year`.

You could also have links that lead to the next and the previous months by linking to the same page with a route value of `prevTime.Month` and `prevTime.Year` (where `var prevTime = selectedTime.AddMonths(-1)`) or `nextTime.Month` and `nextTime.Year` (where `var nextTime = selectedTime.AddMonths(1)`).

Comment: Your idea is very good, but what happens if pressing (e.g.) Previous you have to change the year, also? How is it possible to pass the new value of the year, not to break functionality ?

Comment: I added some code to prevent the situation I explained in my comment.

Comment: @OctavianEpure If `selectedTime` is a `DateTime`, then the `AddMonths` method will take care of changing the year. In any case, you'll have to pass the month and the year as route values. I'd advise that you pass them as separate arguments in the action method, as I'm not sure whether they can be resolved by the framework as a `DateTime` struct.